# Why is my Workspace switcher view skewed

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspace-switcher

I have been using Workspace switcher in Ubuntu just fine but recently have encountered this problem. The windows in the switcher don't fill the screen. I must have pressed some combination of buttons somehow but can't find any information anywhere in regards to resizing them.

As you can see in the screen shot it looks like a perspective view or something.

[image: Workspace switcher skewed]

I should also add I have a dual monitor setup and nvidia graphics. The switcher still works but the fact the screens don't fit my actual screens is driving me nuts. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did someone mess with ccsm options? Coz its an option there...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I found the answer in CSSM. I had the expo plugin setting on tilt somehow. I set it back to none and now all is back to normal.

Comment: Can you post the above comment as an answer please? Then wait 24 hours & mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in Compiz Config Settings Manager. Under the desktop setting I clicked on the Expo window,then from the Appearance tab set the Deformation to None.